# filing and gtk together - possible?

Tags: c, file-io, gtk

i m new to gtk so wanted to know if filing and gtk be used together in C?
as in, can i read from a .txt file and then display it ,in maybe a label or something, using gtk in the same code? if yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can read from a text file using [`g_file_get_contents`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-file-get-contents) (simple) or the [`GFile`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/stable/GFile.html) APIs (more powerful.) Most likely you will use a [`GtkTextBuffer`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html) to display the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, as GTK uses plain C. For example:

## include

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    /*read text from file*/
    FILE *fp;
    char string[128];
    if((fp = fopen("file.txt", "r"))==NULL) {
     printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    }

    while(!feof(fp)) {
       fgets(string, 126, fp); 
    }

    fclose(fp);

    /*create gtk widgets*/
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;


    //initialise gtk
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label(string);



    //pack button inside window
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);

    //display widgets

    gtk_widget_show(button);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```